# How to set quota for search queries and avoid pagination eating up the quota

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, pagination

I've a task to limit user search to 10 queries per day.

I added column to users table `count_search` which starts at 0 and goes up to 10 as uses search. Once he hits 10, query breaks. This value is reset to 0 after 24 hours.

This is all relatively simple. My problem is pagination.

I cannot distinguish between new search and pagination queries, so count_search goes up even for going through pages.

What are my options?

I can think of 1 thing, simply grab all data and make pagination browser side using jquery.

Any ideas, solutions to similar problems?

Comment: If it's a pagination click, then count_search -1 ?

Comment: @RobertRozas THat will make it very easy to avoid limitation doesn't it? Simply keyword search directly on page 2.

Comment: Nope...in the way you have your app it always sum 1... then it will be a  + 1 - 1(sum = 0) so there will be no change in the database column

Comment: So you need to figure out how to distinguish between them?  What makes the query unique in your eyes?  I assume the WHERE criteria in the search.  Order by and limit are related to 'pagination'.  So, compare and determine if its a new search or pagination.  Maybe use a session to store the base SELECT statement and use that to compare against.

Comment: Add your counter code, add your GET string for pagination.

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey yes I will add it, give me a minute to finish it.

Comment: Oeh I like this problem... You could cache the query (the textual query, not the result) and fetch it from cache. If it's in the cache, don't +1, if it's not, it's a new query. Cache could be `$_SESSION`, APC, db etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the query (the textual query, not the result) and fetch it from cache. If it's in the cache, don't +1, if it's not, it's a new query. Cache could be `$_SESSION`, APC, db etc.

```
function query_results( $sqlWithoutPager ) {
  if ( $sqlWithoutPager not exists in user's cache ) {
    counter++
  }

  if ( counter > 10 ) {
    // I think not!
    return
  }

  // add pager to query

  // do query and return 1 page of results
}
```

I'd just save the query cache, not the counter, because the cache length is the counter. More db tables.

`$_SESSION` is probably a bad idea, because the user can kill their session and start a new one (probably).

APC would work, but I don't know if you have it, (and it's not persistent).

Answer (score 0):

I went with client side pagination, as this seemed cleanest way to achieve quota problems.